# RxJava Retrofit2 api multiple calls using subscribe or flatmap

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-android

I am making an API call using Retrofit2 and RxJava. The thing is that I want to make a second API call with the response (in this case an integer) received from the first api call. My doubt regards that both

`Disposable subscribe(@NonNull Consumer<? super T> onSuccess, @NonNull Consumer<? super Throwable> onError)`
method and

```
    <R> Single<R> flatMap(@NonNull Function<? super T, ? extends SingleSource<? extends R>> mapper
```

look like are able to use the result of the first api call to call a second api call with it. So, **which method, either `subscribe` or `flatMap` should I use to make a second api call with the result of the first and why? Do I have to use one or the other depending on whether the first api call's result is iterable or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
fun firstRequest(): Single<Int> = Single.just(10)

fun secondRequest(valueFromFirst: Int): Single<Int> = Single.just(valueFromFirst*2)

fun mappedRequest(): Single<Int> {
  return firstRequest().flatMap {
    secondRequest(it)
  }
}
```

So, now you can have the mappedRequest() accessible from everywhere. You can "prepare" your request by doing:

`val requestSingle = mappedRequest()`

In this case, you have only the single. The request is not running yet, but is ready to run. To effectively run it:

`requestSingle.subscribe { handleResult(it) }`

Comment: then, I guess, you can confirm me flatMap is the optimal one to use for this use case right?

Comment: Yeah I think so. There are other alternatives, like subscribing to the first, which will subscribe to the second. But IMO using flatMap is a lot better as we can put all the logic in a single place.